# Браузер подставляет данные в форму неверно

Tags: html, form

На сайте есть две html формы: одна для регистрации и другая для входа зарегистрированных пользователей. Такая проблема: если браузер запоминает логин и пароль в форме для входа, то он подставляет эти данные также и в форму для регистрации, причём подставляет неправильно - логин в поле для email. Как запретить браузеру подставлять данные в форму для регистрации?

```html
<form id="regform" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">     
<p>
<input type='text' name='login' id="username" value="" placeholder ="логин" required/>
</p>
<p>
<input type='email' name='email' value="" placeholder ="почта" required/>
</p>
<p>
<input type='password' name='password' value placeholder ="пароль" required/>
</p>
<p>
<center><input type='submit' name='reg' value='Готово'/></center>
</p>
</form>
```

```html
<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' autocomplete="off">
 <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Логин:</td>
  <td>
   <input type='text' name='login'/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Пароль:</td>
  <td>
   <input type='password' name='password'/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan='2'>
    <br><center><input type='submit' value = 'Войти' /></center>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan='2'>
    <br/><a href="reset.php" class="interfacelink">восстановить пароль</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

[image: форма регистрации]

Comment: Проблема актуальна для Chrome, в Firefox работает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключайте [автозаполнение полей](https://webref.ru/html/input/autocomplete) форм регистрации и авторизации таким образом (пример одного поля):

```
<input name="pass" type="password" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Автозаполнение отключил, куки удалил. Проблема осталась. Браузер предлагает запомнить логин и пароль для сайта, и далее опять неверно подставляет данные в форму регистрации. В форму для входа данные подставляются верно.

Comment: @Igor, дополните вопрос html кодом input'ов логина и пароля из формы регистрации и авторизации.

Comment: @Igor, пропишите для каждого input в форме регистрации `autocomplete="new-data"`. Современные браузеры ведут себя не совсем так как это предполагалось: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

Comment: autocomplete="new-password" сработало. Спасибо!